# JavaScript Content Not Loading On Page (epub.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use epub.js library, and am trying to get the barebones running. The problem is the ebook is not displaying in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/epubjs/dist/epub.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        
    <div id="area"></div>
    
    </body>

    <script>
      var book = ePub("steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub", { openAs: "epub" });
      var rendition = book.renderTo("area", {width: 600, height: 400});
      var displayed = rendition.display();  

      book.renderTo("area", { method: "default", width: "100%", height: "100%" });

    </script>
</html>
```

I have the `steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub` in my directory, but it's just a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your path is incorrect. Use the correct path if the file is in the same directory where you are keeping the HTML.

```
 <script>
      var book = ePub("./steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub", { openAs: "epub" });
      var rendition = book.renderTo("area", {width: 600, height: 400});
      var displayed = rendition.display();  

      // book.renderTo("area", { method: "default", width: "100%", height: "100%" }); // why are you rendering it again?

    </script>
```

You can check the documentation [here](http://futurepress.org/).

Comment: It's unfortunately still loading a blank page with an empty document. Tried using "./steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub" and "http://127.0.0.1:5500/steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub". The <div id="area> element remains empty

Comment: I am sure that the path is not given correctly. Where are you keeping your `epub` file?

Comment: In the root directory. I have `index.html` and `steinbeck-of-mice-and-men.epub`, that is all

Comment: whats in network tab